# How to prevent any update in PHP MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, crud

How can we stop update in phpmysql database?

I have designed a full functional CRUD admin panel for a sample Ecommerce website. Its a sample/demo website for my portfolio. I show the admin panel dashboard to many people/users. I don't want the people/users to change any thing from the admin panel dashboard connected to the phpmysql database.

Changing all the CRUD queries can solve this problem but it's not the practical solution as there are many CRUD queries in the admin dashboard of the Ecommerce website.

Is there any other way to stop the updates in the database?

Comment: Maybe creating a test database for testing user

Comment: The database contains lot of data of the Ecommerce website. Creating a new database will not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another username, another database and password, and it's done.

If for some weird reason you cannot just at least create another database in your server for this propose you can put everything inside the .json objects, but you'll need chance all your connection classes and fetching methods.

So go for the first approach and create another database at least and migrate the production to this one and just use if for testing.

Comment: The database contains lot of data of the Ecommerce website. Creating a new database will not work in this case.